# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar un " " en un arreglo en java?

Tags: java, encriptación

Tengo que realizar un ejercicio que consta de encriptar un texto ingresado por el usuario siguiendo unas reglas. Una de ellas es que los espacios son cambiados por una U o V dependiendo de la clave. Ya realice la encriptación, pero estoy atascado para reemplazar los espacios en el texto.
Este es mi codigo realizado hasta el momento:

Clase para pedir los datos:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Datos {
    String palabrita;
    char caracter[];
    int clave;
    public void pedirDatitos(){
        palabrita = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese la palabra a encriptar: ");
        caracter = palabrita.toCharArray();/*Convierto el texto ingresado en un array de caracteres para facilitar la encriptación*/
        clave = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el número clave: "));
    }
}
```

Clase para la encriptación:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Calculo {
    Datos obj = new Datos();
    String abece = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    char [] encriptada;
    char abecedario[] = abece.toCharArray();
    public void Encriptacion(){
        obj.pedirDatitos();
        encriptada = new char[obj.caracter.length];
        for(int i=0;i<abecedario.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<obj.caracter.length;j++){
                if(obj.clave==1){
                    if(abecedario[i]==obj.caracter[j]){
                    encriptada[j] = abecedario[i+1];
                    }
                }else{
                    if(abecedario[i]==obj.caracter[j]){
                    encriptada[j] = abecedario[i+2];
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    public void mostrarResult(){
        String mostrar="";
        for(int i=0;i<encriptada.length;i++){
            mostrar += encriptada[i]+"";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mostrar);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estaba pensando si te refieres a que una palabra por ejemplo "Camilo Guitiérrez en StackOverflow" lo conviertes a un array en en cada uno de sus elementos reemplazar  los espacios?

Comment: no, lo que hago es convertir el texto ingresado por el usuario a un array de caracteres para asi facilitar la encriptación. Solamente reemplazando los espacios deberia quedar: CamiloVGutierrezVenVStackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Para reemplazar los espacios usa, según sea el caso para reemplazar por `U` o `V`:

```
cadena.replaceAll("\\s+", 'U')
```

o

```
cadena.replaceAll("\\s+", 'V')
```

---

Actualización:

Si deseas reemplazar los elementos del array de caracteres. A partir del array de elementos puedes iterar cada carácter y realizar el reemplazo, por ejemplo:

```
 ...
 ...
 palabrita = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingrese la palabra a encriptar: ");
 caracter = palabrita.toCharArray();/*Convierto el texto ingresado en un array de caracteres para facilitar la encriptación*/

 //Itera y reemplaza espacios en cada caracter, almacena valor final en "cadenaFinal". 
 final StringBuffer cadenaFinal = new StringBuffer();
 palabrita.chars().forEachOrdered(i -> cadenaFinal.append(String.valueOf((char) i).replaceAll("\\s+", "V")));
 System.out.println(cadenaFinal);
...
...
```

De esta forma al ingresar por ejemplo:

```
Camilo Gutiérrez en Stackoverflow.com
```

tendrías como resultado

```
CamiloVGutiérrezVenVStackoverflow.com
```